# Lua script for creating a folder according to artist metatag with mpv player on windows

Tags: lua, tagging, mpv, lua-scripting-library

I watn to make mpv player like itunes library which organizes media library according to the tags of the file.

For start I want to make script for mpv player that creates a folder according to artist metatag.

When i add this keybinding in input.conf file, it copies the file to folder i want. But i want mpv script to copy the file to the path name according to the artist metatag of the file.

ctrl+m run cmd /c copy ${path} D:\path\to_file; show-text "copied to ${path}"

Answer (score 0):

I somehow achieved this by this keybinding in input.conf file

```
Ctrl+m run cmd /c copy ${path} D:\path\${metadata/by-key/artist}\ ; show-text "copied to ${path}" 10000
```

but it needs to have folder with that name otherwise it doesn't copy.